# USING AVERAGEIFS with value >

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to use AVERAGEIFS using several criteria:

- Criteria 1: column A must contain a particular word;
- Criteria 2: column B must also contain a particular word (different from Column A)
- criteria 3: values in column C where the value is >300.

I am trying to get the average number of Column A (column A contains text) based on the criteria mentioned. Is this possible?

Comment: Welcome.  I am confused when you say you are trying to get an average number of column `A` when column `A` contains text. Can you please provide an example of what you are looking for?

Comment: What spreadsheet program are you using?   Excel?   (What version?)

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you can use **AVERAGEIFS** function:

```
=AVERAGEIFS(C1:C13,A1:A13,"a",B1:B13,"aa",C1:C13,">300")
```

[image]